# I am new to LWC and stuck badly in getting the old field values

Tags: lwc-wire-adapter, wire, lightning-web-components

```
if (data) {
        this.account    = data;
        let modifiedDate= this.account.lastModifiedDate;
        let oldValueRate= getFieldValue(this.account, RATING_FIELD) ?getFieldValue(this.account, RATING_FIELD) : ''
        console.log('oldValueRate  >>>', oldValueRate);
                        
        const alertHotKey = `${this.recordId}`;                
        const alertHotAlreadyShown =sessionStorage.getItem(alertHotKey);
        
        if(!this.lastModifiedDate) {
            this.lastModifiedDate = this.account.lastModifiedDate;
        }

        
        if (modifiedDate != this.lastModifiedDate ) {
            let rate = getFieldValue(this.account, RATING_FIELD) ?getFieldValue(this.account, RATING_FIELD) : ''
            let usrfield = getFieldValue(this.account, USER_FIELD) ?getFieldValue(this.account, USER_FIELD) : ''           

            if( rate='Hot')
            {
                
                    alert('YOU HAVE SELECTED ACCOUNT RATING From '+oldValueRate+'to '+ rate);
                                 
            }

        }
```

**Note**
when I first refresh the page after deploying code, get the old field value suppose if its oldvalueRate='warm' get warm in console. But when I update the rating to 'Hot' value in oldvalueRate='Hot' oldvalue rate gets hot. I want to show old and new  value in alert message.

Answer (score 2):

Since the update doesn't happen in your LWC, you have to be sure history tracking is enabled for Rating field:

1. From Setup, click on **Object Manager** and select *Account*.
2. Open *Fields & Relationships* tab and click on **Set History Tracking**
3. If *Enable Account History* isn't selected, tick it.
4. Select *Rating* and any other field you want to track, then click **Save**

Now you can query `AccountHistory` object. **Beware**: if the history for Account Rating wasn't already enabled there will be no records for it, but as soon as you update an account changing its rating, a new history record will be created.

In your Apex controller you could define an AuraEnabled method for each field history you want to get:

```java
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static List<AccountHistory> getRatingHistory(Id accountId) {
    return [SELECT OldValue, NewValue
            FROM AccountHistory
            WHERE Field = 'Rating' AND AccountId = :accountId
            ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC
            LIMIT 1];
}
```

In JS controller you must import that method, then you can wire it storing both old and new value (and the whole wired object if needed for `refreshApex`):

```js
@api recordId;

ratingOldValue; // this will be set only if at least one record of history is found
ratingCurrentValue;
wiredRatingHistory; // this property can be used with refreshApex

@wire(getRatingHistory, { accountId: '$recordId' })
fetchRatingHistory(result) {
    this.wiredRatingHistory = result;
    const { data, error } = result;
    if (data) {
        if (data.length) {
            this.ratingOldValue = data[0].OldValue;
            this.ratingCurrentValue = data[0].NewValue;
        }
    } else if (error) {
        console.log('getRatingHistory error:', error);
    }
}
```

Finally you can modify the alert block to show both old and new value:

```js
if (data) {
    this.account = data;
    let modifiedDate = this.account.lastModifiedDate;
    const oldValueRate = this.ratingOldValue || '';

    const alertHotKey = `${this.recordId}`;                
    const alertHotAlreadyShown =sessionStorage.getItem(alertHotKey);
    
    if(!this.lastModifiedDate) {
        this.lastModifiedDate = this.account.lastModifiedDate;
    }
    
    if (modifiedDate != this.lastModifiedDate) {
        let rate = getFieldValue(this.account, RATING_FIELD) || ''
        let usrfield = getFieldValue(this.account, USER_FIELD) || ''           

        if (rate=='Hot') {
            alert('YOU HAVE SELECTED ACCOUNT RATING From '+oldValueRate+' to '+ rate);
        }
    }
}
```